# Unity LookAt() function is behaving strangely

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, transform

So I was testing 2D sprites in my game when I noticed that the LookAt() function was behaving weirdly. I was pointing the sprite towards the camera to achieve a flat look when I noticed that the image wasn't looking the right way.
The sprite I used looked like this (30 seconds in MSPaint)
[image]

and this is what it looked like in the editor

[image]

However, when I run it the sprite seems to look in some other strange direction not relating to the camera itself.

[image]

I just used the standard LookAt function, setting the z value to transform.position.z to limit the way it looks at things (this wasn't the problem, as upon setting it to obj.transform.z I had a similarly wrong transformation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public Transform obj;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.LookAt (new Vector3( obj.position.x, obj.position.y, transform.position.z), Vector3.up);
}
```

If anyone is willing to give me some pointers of how to fix this, that would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure how you are setting obj in your case, but to use the camera instead you might want to use: `transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position, Vector3.up);` The [CameraFacingBillboard](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=CameraFacingBillboard) script might also be of interest.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that both pictures happen with a different version of code than those you included in the question? If you tried two solutions, it's kind of illogical to include screenshots of one of them and code of the other: please include both in both cases. Although it's pretty trivial, it makes understanding the problem easier.

Comment: Also, because first screenshot picture doesn't have any kind of lighting, it's impossible to understand from the picture where the pic is facing: to the lower-left or to the upper-right.

Comment: Worth taking a look at the rotation axes of the sprite, the LookAt function behaves oddly with 2D objects. I had this problem with a game I was working on once and it was entirely the rotations around an unintended axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem may occur if the camera doesn't have rotation matching the rotation of Sprite. If you use for the camera:

```
transform.LookAt(yourSprite.transform.position, Vector3.up);
```

and for the sprite:

```
transform.LookAt(yourCamera.transform.position, Vector3.up);
```

they will both "LookAt" each other.

If you can't/don't want to rotate the camera, the sprite would have to match the camera rotation, not "LookAt" the camera position. It all depends on camera rotation, and on what you want to achieve.